# wifi don't work with xubuntu on dell inspiron 10

Tags: wireless, xubuntu

I 've installed xubuntu 16.04 on a dell inspiron mini 10. It 's look working OK but I can't enable the wifi.
What should I do about this?

Comment: type this command into the terminal `lspci -nn -d 14e4:`  If it says Broadcom anywhere ( for example my output is: `0c:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Broadcom Corporation NetXtreme BCM5761 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe [14e4:1681] (rev 10)` ) then follow the answer here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers

Answer (score 0):

Do you use an internet adapter or an ethernet cable? If you use an adapter, try unplugging it for a while. (5 minutes)
Usually that fixes it for me, if the adapter does not work the network icon won't show up.

Comment: Please run the ubuntu forums wireless script (github.com/UbuntuForums/wireless-info) and paste the results into paste.ubuntu.com then edit your question to include a link to it